# Best Way to Handle Multiple Selects Per Object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering for a good while now about the best method to retrieve data from multiple tables within my database. Sadly I couldn't find anything to actually help me understand what the right way to do so is.

Let's say I have a table of content pages named **ContentPages**. This table consists the following fields:

```
PageID
PageTitle
PageContent
```

Now, in addition to the **ContentPages** table I have also got the table **ContentPagesTags** which is in charge of storing the tags which describe best what the page is about (just like in this very website - stackoverflow, where you get to apply specific tags to your question). The **ContentPagesTags** table consists of the following fields:

```
PageID
TagID
```

The **ContentPagesTags** table is in charge of the relationship between the pages and the attached tags. The **TagID** field is taken from the last table, **PageTags**, which stores all of the possible tags which can be applied on a content page. The last table structure looks like this:

```
TagID
TagTitle
```

That's pretty much it. Now, whenever I want to retrieve a **ContentPage** object which extracts the needed information from its data-table, I also want to load an array of all the related tags. By default, what I have been doing so far is running two separate queries in order to achieve my goal:

```
SELECT * FROM ContentPages
```

And then running the next query per each page before returning the **ContentPage** object:

```
SELECT * FROM ContentPagesTags WHERE PageID = @PageID
```

With **PageID** being the ID of the current page I am building an object of.

To sum it all up I am running (at least) two queries per each Content Page object in order to retrieve all of the needed information. In this particular example I only showed what I do in order to extract information from one more table, but in time I find myself running multiple queries per each object in order to get my required information (for instance, other than the page tags I might as well want to select the page comments, the page drafts and additional information I might consider needed). This, eventually, gets me to query multiple commands, which makes my web-application run much slower than expected.

I am pretty sure there's a better, faster and more-efficient way to handle such tasks. Would be glad to get a heads-up on this subject in order to improve my knowledge regarding different SQL selects and how to handle massive amount of data requested by the user without turning to multiple selects per each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for clarification regarding the question I asked in a comment on the Original Question, I can at least say this:

From a pure "query performance" stand-point, this information is disparate in terms of not being related to each other (i.e. [Tags] and [Comments] tables) outside of the `PageID` relationship, but certainly not in terms of a row-by-row basis between these extra tables. As such, there is nothing more to do that can gain efficiency at the query level outside of:

- Make sure you have the `PageID` Foreign Keyed between all subtables back to the `[ContentPages]` table.
- Make sure you have indexes on the `PageID` field in each of the subtables (non-clustered should be fine and a FILLFACTOR of 90 - 100, depending on usage pattern).
- Make sure to perform index maintenance regularly. At least do REORGANIZE somewhat frequently and REBUILD when necessary.
- Make sure that the tables are properly modeled: use *appropriate* datatypes (i.e. don't use INT to store values of 1 - 10 that will never, ever go above 10 or 50 at the worst, just because it is easier to code `int` at the app layer; don't use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for any PKs or Clustered Indexes; etc.). Seriously: *poor data modeling (datatypes as well as structure) can hurt overall performance of some, or even all, queries such that no amount of indexes, or any other features or tricks, will help*.
- If you have Enterprise Edition, consider enabling Row or Page Compression (is a feature of an index), especially for tables like `[Comments]` or even a large association table such as `[ContentPagesTags]` if it will be really large (in terms of row count) as compression allows for using smaller fixed-length datatypes to store values that are declared as larger types. Meaning: if you have an `INT` (4 bytes) or `BIGINT` (8 bytes) for `TagID` then it will be a short while before the IDENTITY value needs more than the 2 bytes used by the `SMALLINT` datatype, and a great while before you exceed the 4 bytes of the `INT` datatype, *but* SQL Server will store a value of **1005** in a 2 byte space *as if* it were a `SMALLINT`. Essentially, reducing row-size will fit more rows on each 8k datapage (which is how SQL Server reads and stores data) and hence reduces physical IO and makes better use of the data pages that are cached in memory.
- If concurrency is (or becomes) an issue, check out [Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb.aspx).

Now, from an application / process stand-point, you want to reduce the number of connections / calls. You could try to merge some of the info into CSV or XML fields to end up as 1-to-1 with each `PageID` / `PageContent` row, but this is actually less efficient than just letting the RDBMS give you the data in its simplest form. It certainly can't be faster to take extra time to convert INT values into strings to then merge into a larger CSV or XML string, only to have the app layer spend even more time unpackaging it.

Instead, you can both reduce the number of calls and not increase operational time / complexity by returning multiple result sets. For example:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPageData
(
  @PageID INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT fields
FROM   [Page] pg
WHERE  pg.PageID = @PageID;

SELECT tag.TagID,
       tag.TagTitle
FROM   [PageTags] tag
INNER JOIN  [ContentPagesTags] cpt
        ON  cpt.TagID = tag.TagID
WHERE  cpt.PageID = @PageID;

SELECT cmt.CommentID,
       cmt.Comment
       cmd.CommentCreatedOn
FROM   [PageComments] cmt
WHERE  cmt.PageID = @PageID
ORDER BY cmt.CommentCreatedOn ASC;
```

And cycle through the result sets via [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx).

---

But, just for the record, I don't really think that calling three separate "get" stored procedures for this info would really increase the total time of the operation to fill out each page all that much. I would suggest doing some performance testing of both methods first to ensure that you aren't solving a problem that is more perception/theory than reality :-).

**EDIT:**
Notes:

- Multiple result sets (not the SQL Server M.A.R.S. feature "Multiple Active Result Sets") is not specific to stored procedures. You could just as well issue multiple parameterized SELECT statements via the SqlCommand:

  ```
  string _Query = @"
  SELECT fields
  FROM   [Page] pg
  WHERE  pg.PageID = @PageID;

  SELECT tag.TagID,
         tag.TagTitle
  FROM   [PageTags] tag
  INNER JOIN  [ContentPagesTags] cpt
          ON  cpt.TagID = tag.TagID
  WHERE  cpt.PageID = @PageID;

  --assume SELECT statement as shown above for [PageComments]";

  SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(_Query, _SomeSqlConnection);
  _Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

  SqlParameter _ParamPageID = new SqlParameter("@PageID", SqlDbType.Int);
  _ParamPageID.Value = _PageID;
  _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamPageID);
  ```
- If you are using `SqlDataReader.Read()` it would be something like the following. Please note that I am purposefully showing multiple ways of getting the values out of the `_Reader` just to show options. Also, the number of Tags and/or Comments is really irrelevant from a CPU perspective. More items does equate to more memory, but no way around that (unless you use AJAX to build the page one item at a time and never pull the full set into memory, but I highly doubt a single page would have enough tags and comments to even be noticeable).

  ```
  // assume the code block above is right here

  SqlDataReader _Reader;
  _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();

  if (_Reader.HasRows)
  {
     // only 1 row returned from [ContentPages] table
     _Reader.Read();
     PageObject.Title = _Reader["PageTitle"].ToString();
     PageObject.Content = _Reader["PageContent"].ToString();
     PageObject.ModifiedOn = (DateTime)_Reader["LastModifiedDate"];

     _Reader.NextResult(); // move to next result set
     while (_Reader.Read()) // retrieve 0 - n rows
     {
        TagCollection.Add((int)_Reader["TagID"], _Reader["TagTitle"].ToString());
     }

     _Reader.NextResult(); // move to next result set
     while (_Reader.Read()) // retrieve 0 - n rows
     {
        CommentCollection.Add(new PageComment(
                _Reader.GetInt32(0),
                _Reader.GetString(1),
                _Reader.GetDateTime(2)
                      ));
     }
  }
  else
  {
      throw new Exception("PageID " + _PageID.ToString()
                  + " does not exist. What were you thinking??!?");
  }
  ```
- You can also load multiple result sets into a `DataSet` and each result set will be its own `DataTable`. For details please see the MSDN page for [DataSet.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef0k7a.aspx)

  ```
  // assume the code block 2 blocks above is right here

  SqlDataReader _Reader;
  _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
  DataSet _Results = new DataSet();

  if (_Reader.HasRows)
  {
     _Results.Load(_Reader, LoadOption.Upsert, "Content", "Tags", "Comments");
  }
  else
  {
      throw new Exception("PageID " + _PageID.ToString()
                  + " does not exist. What were you thinking??!?");
  }
  ```

Comment: Never got the chance to work with stored procedures before. Your answer is well typed and explained, but one single thing I've got missing. I would be very glad if you could alter your original answer to show a short example of how the data rows would look like upon selecting one page with, let's say, 3 tags and 3 different comments. So far when I've been fetching rows via the SqlDataReader it was for the purpose of moving towards the next page, but your answer seems to suggest fetching to go through the page comments and tags. Would be very kind of you if you could exhibit a little bit.

Comment: Despite my request at my previous comment, I thank you for your input.

Comment: @TommyNaidich : you are welcome. Yes, I can update, but just FYI, multiple result sets (_not_ the SQL Server `M.A.R.S.` feature "Multiple **Active** Result Sets") is not specific to stored procedures. You could just as well issue multiple parameterized SELECT statements via the SqlCommand (e.g. "SELECT 1; SELECT 2;" is two result sets). I don't use DataSets, but if you load a DataSet from a query like this you will get one DataTable per result set.

Comment: I understand. Would still be very glad to see a short example of how many rows I would get per call (considering 3 different comments and 3 different tags per page, for instance), and how the data would be stored. This would help me understand the whole concept much better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TommyNaidich : Got part of it done. Will do the next part now. Again, I am assuming you are only interested in a single PageID's worth of data at a time, right?

Comment: That's correct. I only want to see the actual result(s) the SqlDataReader object will retrieve per one single Page ID. The code-implementation is not an issue to me, however I still thank you for your will to help.

Comment: @TommyNaidich : Done (I think ;). Please let me know if it all makes sense. If not then please specify what else needs clarification.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to see. This was very helping and I hope I'll get it right in time when I get to practice this. Once again, and this time for the last time I hope - thank you very much for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the tags in a delimited list.  You can do this in SQL Server with the following query:

```
select cp.*,
       stuff((select ', ' + TagTitle
              from ContentPagesTags cpt join
                   PageTags pt
                   on cpt.TagId = pt.TagId
              where cpt.PageId = cp.PageId
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '') as Tags
from ContentPages cp;
```

The syntax for the string concatenation is, shall I say, less than intuitive.  Other databases have nice functions for this (such as `listagg()` and `group_concat()`).  But, the performance is usually quite reasonable, particularly if you have the appropriate indexes (which include `ContentPagesTags(PageId, TagId)`).

Comment: To be honest this method seems a bit unprofessional. If I understood it right, the query suggested by you provides a string made out of XML lines. This seems like something we do whilst not knowing the actual way to handle our task, no offence. Also, isn't there a shorter version of this example? As I explained I might need to include your example not once but multiple times within my code in order to select all of the information I need. This can get really messy.

Comment: This is how you do string concatenation in SQL Server, unless you decide to write your own function.  You can take it up with Microsoft if you don't like it.

Comment: I believe it came out the wrong way - I didn't mean to sound unsatisfied by your answer, but simply wanted to know if there's an easier way to achieve this goal. I didn't specifically ask for a method to make a string concatenation, as mentioned in your last comment, but to retrieve multiple rows per each object I create. After all, as I have already mentioned, it sums up to numerous lines and the final SQL query would turn pretty fat and massive. Simply wanted to know if there's an easier (shorter) method.

Comment: @TommyNaidich . . . If there were a better method, I would have put it in my answer.  Other databases have functions such as `listagg()`, `stringagg()`, and `group_concat()`, but not SQL Server.  It does take some getting used to, but this method works fine.